# Im studying Gradient Descent, at this code precision meaning is what?

Tags: python, gradient-descent

I'm studying Gradient Descent by myself.
Because using to resume for university admission.
Is the meaning of precision an allowable value of error?

```
x_old = 0
x_new = 6 # The algorithm starts at x=6
eps = 0.01 # step size
precision = 0.00001

def f_prime(x):
    return 4 * x**3 - 9 * x**2

while abs(x_new - x_old) > precision:
    x_old = x_new
    x_new = x_old - eps * f_prime(x_old)

print("Local minimum occurs at: " + str(x_new))
```

Comment: The algorithm you are using doesn't provide a guarantee of how close you are to the right answer. It just stops when the change in `x` from one step to the next is smaller than `precision`. In many cases that will mean you are very close to the right answer, but it depends on the function you are working with.

Comment: Hi, the 'precision' seems like that stop your Gradient Descent.

Comment: If you want to understand why a variable in the code you were shown has the name that it does, you should *ask the author*. Or re-read the surrounding text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that precision is a means to check for convergence: if the last iteration of gradient descent caused only a small change, then stop.

This approach is not very robust. First, a small change in a single iteration is not a strong indication for convergence. It would be better to look for a small change in several consecutive iterations. Second, the process might not converge at all, so some sort of guard against an infinite loop should be used.

Comment: Thanks to answering, then how can make small change in several consecutive iterations? Can  i get advice? :)

Comment: Additonaly, why might the process not converge at all?

Comment: The process may fail to converge if the chosen step size is too large. Take, for example, the function f(x) = x^2. Suppose we start at x_new = -1 and take eps = 1 (an unreasonably huge step size just for the sake of the example). Then it is simple to check that x_new will infinitely oscillate between -1 and 1, overshooting the required minimum of 0.